# Saving/loading document state quickly and robustly for image editor

Tags: java, iphone, android, serialization, image-processing

I'm looking for some critique on my approach for storing the state of a bitmap editor for  Android and iPhone mobile phones. Even a "Looks fine to me!" response would be great!

In the application, the current user document contains several bitmap layers (each maybe 1024 by 768 pixels) that can each be painted on. The basic requirements for the application  are:

1. I need to be able to save and restore the document state.
2. When the user quits the application or gets a phone call, I need to be able to save the document state quickly (within about 2 seconds).
3. If the application crashes, I need to be able to restore the document state (it's OK if the user loses maybe 30 seconds of work though).

For 1, I cannot find any open file formats that support layers. I was going to go with the following file structure for storing my document:

```
document_folder/
  layer1.png
  layer2.png
  ...
  metadata.xml
```

The layers are just stored as .png files and the .xml file contains data such as which layers are currently visible. The document folder can either be opened as is by the application or the folder can be stored in a .zip file. This seems like a nice simple format for other applications to work with too.

In addition to .png files, I will also allow layers to be saved in a custom .raw file format which contain unprocessed raw pixel data from bitmaps. I can save these very quickly on the phone (<0.5s) whereas .png files take a second or two.

My plan for quick-saving the document was, on start-up, to create a folder called /autosave, and save .raw versions of all the layers there. After a few editing commands on one layer, I would then update the .raw file for that layer in a background thread. For robustness when saving, I would save the layer as e.g. layer1_tmp.raw and when I've confirmed the file has been fully written, replace layer1.raw with this file.

Should the application crash during use, I would just reopen the /autosave folder. When the application is closed or the user gets a phone call, I just have to update the last modified layer to autosave. When the user wants to save, I just convert all the .raw files to .png files and then zip the folder.

What do you think? Are there any obvious flaws? Is there a simpler way? Am I reinventing the wheel somehow? Thanks.

Comment: @tifftuff: "When the user quits the application or gets a phone call, I need to be able to save the document state quickly (within about 2 seconds)" -- that may not be possible just due to the speed of writing to flash. Flash is very unpredictable in terms of writes, as it depends on things like wear leveling. Otherwise, I see nothing particularly wrong with your strategy, at least *vis a vis* Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare: In Android, I can copy 1.5Mb of pixel bytes from a Bitmap object into a file via RandomAccessFile.write and then close the file within ~0.1s. If I call .sync() on the file descriptor (to force the writing to be done now), it takes something like 1 to 3 seconds. I won't have enough time to wait for .sync() in the activity onPause() method but I could wait for .close() to be finished. Is this not enough to have a very good chance that the file has actually been written? Any suggestions about what I can do instead if this is not the case? I only need to save one layer (~1.5Mb).

Comment: @tifftuff: All I'm saying is that flash is slow. At the 2010 Google I/O conference, Brad Fitzpatrick cited some experiments he ran, where writing a single byte sporadically would take 200ms, though typically it was sub-millisecond. Be sure your timing tests are done on hardware, as flash as much different characteristics than the hard drive you probably have on your development machine. The less data you write, the faster it will be. For example, perhaps what you are thinking of as a "layer" should just be the pixels that are drawn, not any background, to try to cut that 1.5MB down.

Comment: @CommonsWare: "Be sure your timing tests are done on hardware" - My timings are from a Droid phone. I'm confused at what to do now as, if I assume I won't even be able to save a few bytes in the worst case scenario, I just have to accept that I have no guarantee that I'll be able to save anything when onPause() is called. In which case, how can any Android app be sure they'll be able to save their state? Do you know if managing to call .close() on a output stream means that my bytes have more than likely been written to disk? I can't find much in the documentation about this.

Comment: @tifftuff: "In which case, how can any Android app be sure they'll be able to save their state?" -- apps don't usually up and decide to save 1.5MB of data just because another activity took over the foreground. Again: find a way to save less data. For example, perhaps you use the memento pattern and are persisting just the drawing commands that can recreate a layer from the previously saved layer. "Do you know if managing to call .close() on a output stream means that my bytes have more than likely been written to disk?" -- `flush()` or `close()` should ensure the bytes are written.

Comment: @tifftuff: Also, be sure to save this data in a background thread, such as using an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: "Again: find a way to save less data". This is a tricky problem for a bitmap editor. If I use mementos, the user can still draw over the whole canvas and require me to save a large amount of data. With the command pattern, I would still e.g. have a lot of touch coordinates to save. Given that, in practice, I can usually write a whole bitmap and call close() in ~0.1s in onPause(), do you think this is a reasonable safe approach?  I could alter my recovery method so that e.g. if the last layer file hasn't been saved properly, revert back to a slightly older one.

Comment: @CommonsWare: By the way, if I was to pass my Bitmap object to an AsyncTask to save, what guarantee do I have that the Bitmap will remain in memory for long enough for the AsyncTask to write it to disk?

Comment: @tifftuff: "Given that, in practice, I can usually write a whole bitmap and call close() in ~0.1s in onPause(), do you think this is a reasonable safe approach?" -- if you do the work in a background thread, sure. " if I was to pass my Bitmap object to an AsyncTask to save, what guarantee do I have that the Bitmap will remain in memory for long enough for the AsyncTask to write it to disk?" -- you have as much guarantee as anything. If the user smashes their phone with a sledgehammer, you will lose the `Bitmap`. The `AsyncTask` does not change that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea souds good to me: save the layers in the background, as you go. Any layer that the user isn't currently editing should be queued to be saved as soon as they switch away from it to a different layer. If the app is interrupted, you just have to save the current working layer, which as you say can be done in 0.5s.

Why bother with the png format anyway? You only need it if exporting data to another machine/system, right?

Comment: Very true. Png is only necessary if you want the user to be able to export. So maybe only generate a png if a user clicks export or similar. Otherwise, just use your quick raw format. Your approach sounds great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a great plan there. I would probably go the same way (but that itself doesn't mean anything :-)

What I was thinking is if you could have not only a worker thread saving the file but a complete background service (with a worker thread of course, since a service itself also runs in the main thread).

This way you would have guaranteed that there is always something alive that can handle your layer deltas, regardless if the drawing activity has crashed or someone is calling you. Suddenly you don't have the same timing constraints (the write operation can take 10 seconds if it wants to, your activity is neither blocked, nor dependent of the write operation). Of course your service would then commit suicide when it has emptied its save queue (to save system resources).

What I don't know in order to further promote this idea is how much data you're writing to the raw-file? Do you write the complete 1024x768 layer every time or do you only rewrite the changed parts? I'm also unsure of how the data would actually be transmitted to the service (from the Activity). I don't know if there is a maximum size of a byte-array-extra an Intent can handle.

Hope this gives you further ideas.

Cheers!