# Thread started by an application in android

Tags: android

If I raise a thread in via an Application in Android, how long does the thread life and is active?
Does a thread continue to live when the user leaves the application. If so for how long?

Comment: Also consider setDaemon(true)

Answer (score 0):

Until the Thread completes. You should look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class instead of regular Threads though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah in Android threads are like the old-fashion Java thread. They do not have a predefined lifecylvce like Services, Activities etc. If you start a new thread you must also be responsible of its lifecycle (i.e. terminate it when you do not need it anymore and keep it alive untill you need it).

EDIT: see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#procthread) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898447/how-does-android-handle-background-threads-when-leaving-an-activity). As I was saying, the thread remains alive untill it has work to do. Regard that if the process of your application is destroied by the O.S. then also the thread you have created will be destroyed as well.