# Killing a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread inside an Activity.

Is the thread killed by the system when the Activity terminates, or do I need to manually kill it (say, in onDestory())?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the accepted answer posted here, should answer your question.

[How does Android handle background threads when leaving an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898447/how-does-android-handle-background-threads-when-leaving-an-activity)

i.e. No, Android does not manually kill threads that you create yourself.  You need to clean them up.  See the link above for the full discussion.